# Facebook Open Graph Analytics

Tags: facebook, facebook-like, facebook-opengraph, analytics

I am trying to figure out how many likes came from a facebook fangate page.
For example, 
http://example.com/ has 1000 likes.

The example's fangate page has a "Like" button to http://example.com/

Does Facebook's open graph analytics have a tool to bring up data on where these links come from?

Is there a way to pull up data to analyze this?  Say is there a way I was able to have data that told me

200 Likes came from example fangate page
300 likes came from some other site etc.

Answer (score 0):

You have analyics for the Facebook Fanpage. Not for a URL.

If you are the administrator of the page. acess this link http://www.facebook.com/YOUR_PAGE_HERE/page_insights_likes

You cant see the source of like, but you can see the types of likes. If come from the page, from a like button, from a popup, from timeline, from celphone...